# What is the best way to track and lower GD handles?

Tags: c#, windows, memory, gdi

what is the best way to track and lower GDI windows handles . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two links worth reading...

[Resource Leaks: Detecting, Locating, and Repairing Your Leaky GDI Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx)

[GDI Resource Leaks](http://www.relisoft.com/win32/GdiLeaks.html)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use [IARSN TaskInfo](http://www.iarsn.com/taskinfo.html) to see the number of handles my program uses, GDI included. As for lowering the number of active handles, then I would look at what in your application is using handles.

Things like (but not limited to):

- Pens
- Bitmaps
- Controls (I don't think all of them uses handles)

Do you have a specific problem with too many handles, or perhaps even a handle leak?

Comment: i think so but i am trying to determine how to diagnose this and isolate how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any tool.
Just read GDI handle table with win32 api

Comment: how would you do this . .would this tell you where the handles are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool to track down resource leaks awhile ago. It is hosted on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/leaktrap/). Although it is a native library, I believe it can be used to track down leaks in .NET code as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To track the GDI handles I would suggest [GDIView from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html). It is a freeware which can display how many GDI handles from each type (Pen, Brush, Bitmap, Font, DC, ...) has a process.

Comment: This tool is completely useless. It tells me that I have 24 brushes, 50 bitmaps, 60 fonts, 14 regions and 24 DC's. Which it then calculates to a total sum of 562 GDI handles!! Also Taskmanager tells me that they are 562, but GDIView is not able to give me the required details.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to see the current usage on an end user's machine is to use task manager and look at the column "GDI Handles"

When I suspect I have GDI handle leaks I tend to run through my leak scenario once, force a garbage collection, look at task manager, run the action again with gc and check for a difference. If I find one I have used the .Net Profiler (from SciTech) which can show in detail which object causes the leak and why it is not handed back